# Lorentz curve plot

Tags: r

I need to get a plot of a Lorentz curve of a cumulative variable as a function of the number of observations. I want both axes to be displayed on a percentage basis (e.g. say observations are the number of buyers and the y variable is the amount they bought, buyers are already ranked in descending order, I want to get the plot that says "The top 10% buyers purchased 90% of the total bought"). My dataset is a couple million observations.

What is the best way to do this? Sub-questions:

If I need to add two variables for the quantiles of total observations and total $ bought (so as to use them to plot), what is the object that returns the row number? I tried:

`user_quantile <- row(df)/nrow(df)`

but I get a matrix of identical columns (user_quantile.1, user_quantile.2) of which I only need one column.

Is there instead any way to skip adding percentages as variables and only have them for axes values?

The plot has way to many points than I need to get the line. What is the best approach to minimize the computational effort and get a nice graph?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Roberto, I am having the around the same number of observations! did get the solution? I was also looking forward to see the Lorenz  curve for multiple time period and to see that how large data can be represented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to acquaint yourself with the excellent [RSeek](http://rseek.org) search engine for R content. One quick query for *Lorentz curve* (and *Lorenz curve*) lead to these packages:

- [ineq](http://cran.r-project.org/package=ineq): Measuring inequality, concentration, and poverty
- [reldist](http://cran.r-project.org/package=reldist): Relative Distribution Methods
- [GeoXp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=GeoXp): Interactive exploratory spatial data analysis
- [lawstat](http://cran.r-project.org/package=lawstat): An R package for biostatistics, public policy and law

all of which seem to supply a Lorenz curve function.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the plot done you need first to arrange the raw data.

1) You can use the `cut2()` function from the Hmisc package to cut the data in quantiles. Check the documentation, it's not hard. It's similar to the `cut()` from the base package.

2) After using the `cut2()` function with the income data, you need to compute the frequency of each decile. Use `table()` for that. Then calculate percentages of income for each decile.

3) Now you should have a very small table with the following columns:
Decile, cumulative % of total income.
Add another column with the 45 degree line. Just add a constant cumulative % of income.

```
finaltable$cumulative_equality_line = seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1)
```

4) You can use base graphics or ggplot2 for plotting. I guess you can do it with the info of step 3 or perhaps check out specific plotting questions.

I'll have to do it soon, but i already have the final table. I'll post the code for plotting once i do it.

Good luck!